# How to apply indexing to a type in Java

Tags: java, arrays, indexer

I have a Matrix class in C#, and I am trying to convert the code into a Java class, but I have managed to copy almost every attribute of the .NET class to the Java source code, but I cannot get around applying an indexing structure to the Java type. The Java multidimensional array looks a lot like that used in [C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B). How do I apply the indexer to the Java type like in the .NET code?

***My indexer in C#***

```
class Matrix{
    private int rows;
    private int cols;

    // Declare the multidimensional array
    private double[,] _data;

    // Constructor
    public Matrix(int r, int c){
        this.rows = r;
        this.cols = c;
        // Assign the array
        _data = new double[rows, cols];
    }

    // Apply an indexer struct to the class
    public double this[int row, int column]{
        get{
            return _data[row, column];
        }
        set{
            _data[row, column] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

***Java Matrix class Indexing attempt***

```
class Matrix{
    private int rows;
    private int cols;
    private double[][] _data;
    public Matrix(int r, int c){
        this.rows = r;
        this.cols = c;

        _data = new double[rows][cols];
    }

    // I tried this, but it will not function the way I need it to
    public double get(int row, int col){
        return _data[row][col];
    }
    public boolean isSquare(){
        return this.rows == this.cols;
    }
}
```

The reason why I need this is because the code I have in .NET let's me assign a location in the array like

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix(8, 8);
matrix[0, 0] = 23;
// I need to achieve that in the Java compiler without errors and warnings
```

Comment: `matrix[0,0]=23;` is not going to work. You need to create a setter like `matrix.setValue(0, 0, 23)` which internally accesses your `_data` matrix.

Comment: is ther a way to something like `matrix[0][0]=23` for Java?

Comment: No, you can only to that if `matrix` is a 2d-array. So you could use `matrix._data[0][0]=23`, but then `_data` would need to be at least non-private.

Comment: I needed to wrap the `_data` inside the class so an object of the class functions as the __data_to a programmer but okay, I will just let it go because the Java programming language does not function that way

Comment: Yes, java does not have operator overloading you you cannot use the `[]` operator on an object, only on an array.

Comment: Okay, thanks, let's hope oracle will implement indexing to an object. No wonder I noticed Java objects have methods with integer attributes for getting object that behave like arrays. `gets and sets` with `int` parameters

Comment: They will not do that as operator overloading is a massive change to the language.

Comment: `public void set(double val, int x, int y){
        _data[x][y]=val;
    }` Is the equivalent of the dotnet indexer?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a setter function in Java... Something like this would work:

```
public void setValue ( int rowIndex, int colIndex, double val ) {
    this._data[rowIndex][colIndex] = val;
}
```

And then you need to call the setter function from the object you created. For example, say, you created object m, and then you'd have to call, `m.setValue(rowIndex, colIndex, value);` in order for it to do something.